# Compare with size_t, return int?

Tags: c++, object, vector, int, size-t

I'm writing some code examples from "How to Think Like a Computer Scientist in C++", and this one is about handling playing-card type objects and decks.  I'm facing this situation:

```
int Card::find(const std::vector<Card>& deck) const {
    size_t deckSize = deck.size();
    for (size_t i=0; i<deckSize; i++)
        if (equals(*this, deck[i])) return i;

    return -1;
}
```

I couldn't use ".length()" on a vector in C++ in Visual Studio 2010 as in the text, and instead had to use .size() which returns (I believe) std::size_type.  I figured I could use size_t and get away with it in order to avoid problems on different architectures, as I've been reading, but I'm wondering if I return `i`, but it's bigger than an integer, will I crash the program?

[Edited to be more specific in my question:]
Once I start using vectors for larger things than cards, I considered using unsigned int because of a compiler mismatch warning, but I feel returning an unsigned int or int has a few issues: 1) int will not take a sufficiently large vector index.  2) returning unsigned int will not let me return -1.  3) unsigned int isn't equal to size_t on all architectures (I'm also doing microcontroller programming on an ARM Cortex-M3).

What should I do if I ever have a large enough vector?

Comment: You should consider getting a different C++ book.  There is a list of [good introductory C++ books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c++-book-guide-and-list).  I'm not familiar with _How to Think Like a Computer Scientist in C++_, but its first example has a `void main()` and uses `<iostream.h>`.  It doesn't look promising.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Casting from `size_t` to `int` will not "crash" your program, but it's a bad bad practice. On the other hand, STL includes nice [`find`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/find.html) algorithm for what you are doing.

Comment: I'm leery about using the STL for non-PC programming since I'm also learning to be able to write for microcontrollers (specifically the ARM Cortex-M3).  It seems the STL has the capability to balloon code size if handled improperly.

Comment: You might want to stick to C for these sort of things then, though many here might start yelling :)

Answer (score 2):

int is 32 bit on 32 / 64 bit Windows and Linux. i will get truncated if greater than two at the 31st. you could use unsigned int and your program will be fine unless storing more than 4 G elements in the vector :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  It's just that if I want to return -1 in case no results return, unsigned int would not handle it.  I'll amend my post to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

You can also return `std::pair<size_t, bool>`, similar to `std::map insert()`. Second template argument means success or fail.

If you ok with this, you could also use [boost::optional](http://beta.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

`size_t` is typically an `unsigned int` but you can't rely on that. If it's bigger than an `int` you won't crash, you'll just overflow into a (probably negative) number.

Assuming you're not going to have several tens of thousands of cards in one vector, I'd be happy returning the `int`.

Comment: size_t will probably not be an unsigned int on 64-bit platforms.

Comment: Exactly. That's why you can't rely on that.